# How to reload a level in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a simple 2d rock paper scissors game, in which after each player presses a button they are taken to an endgame screen that has two buttons: exit and play again.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to actually restart the game when the user presses the play again button.Here is what I've tried:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayAgain : MonoBehaviour ,IPointerClickHandler{

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {   
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1").transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameOverScreen").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

}
```

The objects with the tags "Player 1/2/GameOverScreen" are panels,GameOverScreen being the current one.This should (if I'm not wrong) reset all the variables to the value they are given by the first script that should play after the scene is loaded.To make sure of this, I've created a scene execution order like this :

Variables ->Events->OnClickRock/Paper/Scissors->PlayAgain

Here are the other scripts:

Variables:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Variables :MonoBehaviour {
    static public string Player1Choice;
    static public bool Player1Turn=true;
    static public string Player2Choice;
    static public bool Player2Turn=true;
    static public bool GameOver=false;
    static public bool Player1Victory=false;
    static public bool Player2Victory=false;
    static public bool Draw=false;
}
```

Events

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Events : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1").transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameOverScreen").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Variables.Player1Turn == false) {
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player1").transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player2").transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
        }
        if (Variables.GameOver == true) 
        {
            if (Variables.Player1Choice == "rock") 
            {
                if (Variables.Player2Choice == "rock") 
                {
                    Variables.Draw = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Variables.Player2Victory = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Variables.Player1Victory = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Variables.Player1Choice == "paper")
            {
                if (Variables.Player2Choice == "rock")
                {
                    Variables.Player1Victory = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Variables.Draw = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Variables.Player2Victory = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Variables.Player1Choice == "scissors")
            {
                if (Variables.Player2Choice == "rock")
                {
                    Variables.Player2Victory = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Variables.Player1Victory = true;
                }
                else if (Variables.Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Variables.Draw = true;
                }
            }
            if (Variables.Player1Victory == true)
            {
                print("Player 1 won!");
            }
            else if(Variables.Player2Victory == true)
            {
                print("Player 2 won!");
            }
            else
            {
                print("It's a draw!");
            }
            print("Player one chose: " + Variables.Player1Choice);
            print("Player two chose: " + Variables.Player2Choice);

            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player2").transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameOverScreen").transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Application.LoadLevel (0);`?

Comment: @kalamazoowho No - it's worth noting that `Application.LoadLevel()` is obsolete.

Comment: So what should I be doing?This seems so simple yet for some reason I can't for the life of me find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reload the current scene

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex,LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

Comment: It's definetly reloading, but the panels aren't reshaping the way they are supposed to, even though the instructions for that are in the same function that reloads the scene, instead I get to stare at the endgame screen.How do I change that?

Comment: @Radu Harabagiu when you reload the scene it will destroy the objects you have just reshaped, loading the scene with their default values, you should try reshaping the panels after the scene has loaded in a separate function. (perhaps Awake() ) ?

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid-thank you very much for this!